# The word/phrase for a worthless work to do?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> At first sight it might seem ———— to talk about freedom of speech within
> authoritative regimes.

I want to say it is fruitless, has no result, in vain, useless, to talk about freedom of speech within dictatorships.

What is a good word or phrase for the blank? Or maybe one of those I already mentioned is good?

Comment: Have you checked for synonyms of _fruitless_, Sasan? You can also check in dictionaries for example sentences containing _fruitless_, _useless_, _futile_ ....

Comment: You might also look up *pointless.*

Comment: The word _vain_ can be used on its own, by the way: _it might seem vain to ..._ Or there's _naive_, (or _naïve_), _over-optimistic_, _Pollyannaish_. (I think _bootless_ may have had its day!) _it might seem like whistling Dixie to ..._!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian "vain" only has that meaning when used as an attributive adjective, like "vain attempt". Your use sounds like it means they have a high opinion of themself.

Comment: @Barmar  [_it is vain to talk about_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+is+vain+to+talk+about%22&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1708&bih=819&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1980%2Ccd_max%3A2022&ei=rKLMYveNHeuQhbIPl8SOaA&ved=0ahUKEwj3k9Hp7_H4AhVrSEEAHReiAw04FBDh1QMIDQ&uact=5&oq=%22it+is+vain+to+talk+about%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BQghEKABOgQIIRAKSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUJAIWJYXYI8aaAFwAHgAgAFriAG6A5IBAzUuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz). There's a famous line of Jeremy Bentham's: _It is vain to talk of the interest of the community, without understanding what is the interest of the individual.'_

Comment: @Barmar But maybe this usage has died out in the US.

Comment: Indeed, that sounds almost Shakespearean. @OldBrixtonian

Comment: Am I not **Old** Brixtonian? ;-)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for *contradiction in terms* or *misleading*, as in, "It would be misleading to talk of etc.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian So is ‘it is vain to talk …’ still common? Or I should go just with ‘pointless’?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. But I am confused about the most relevant option in this particular context. For example, there are disagreement about ‘vain’, as also raised in the comments here.

Comment: @Sasan It depends on the tone/voice/register of your email/essay/scholarly article. In an _informal_ context, 'vain' _might_ be misunderstood (as we've seen!). But in a _formal_ context I would choose either 'vain' or 'futile'. (According to Bamar, _not_ 'vain' in the US.) Xanne's 'pointless' is quite blunt: it would fit very well in an _informal_ context. Check the shades of meaning of aparente001's and Edwin Ashworth's suggestions. Or just use 'futile'! :-)

Comment: 'Fruitless' sounds perfect - if it's 'fruitless' alone, not anything like 'a fruitless work to do.' 

Either way, in my view word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Answer (score -1):

*Counterintuitive* might be a good choice here. You could also say *unproductive* or *ill-fitting*.

Comment: That fits in the blank, but I don't think it expresses the OP's intent.